# Find time difference between 10.30am to 7.30pm

Tags: c#, datetime

I have two textboxes in which the user will enter `startTime` and `endTime` in 12 hours format (Eg. 10:30 AM to 7:30 PM).

On clicking the `Calculate` button, the user should get the difference between the two times inputted in textbox.

I have not getting what datatype should handle this inputted text.

I would really appreciate if someone could write few lines of program for me to understand better.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow.  This community generally expects questions to show some level of research and effort - have you tried anything yourself that isn't working?

Comment: Have a look at [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx), [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx), [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) and [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I see that you joined today, Welcome to Stackoverflow. Here is what you should try:
Parse both Time using `DateTime.ParseExact` and then calculate their difference like:

```
DateTime  dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact("10:30 AM","h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact("7:30 PM", "h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
TimeSpan difference = dt2 - dt1;

Console.WriteLine(difference.TotalHours);
Console.WriteLine(difference.TotalMinutes);
```

You should put what you have tried in your question and where are you stuck at. You may see http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly parse the textboxes into `DateTime` values called `date1` and `date2` using [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx).

Then calculate the difference using `TimeSpan delta = date2 - date1;`

But what have you tried so far? You need to put more effort into trying things before posting here.

Comment: I tried above steps but this does not work for 12 hours time format

Comment: @user2380981 You will need to specify the 12 hour time format in the parameter to `ParseExact()`. See here for documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx I expect you will need to specify the format as "h:m tt" or possibly as just "t" (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)